# Browserify for multipage website with gulp and factor-bundle

Tags: gulp, browserify, browserify-shim

I am trying to use Browserify with factor-bundle to load specific module on pages.

Here is how I organize my JS source files :

```
bower_compoments
├── jquery/...
├── foundation/...
└── [...]
static/src/js
├── common.js
├── home.js
└── other_page.js
```

Here is my build folder :

```
static/build/js
├── main.js // must be loaded on all pages: bundle of bower_compoments + common.js
├── home.js
└── other_page.js
```

**home.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/build/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/build/js/home.js"></script>
<script> 
    // Trying to load and execute the module
    var home = require('home'); // Raise an error "Module not found"
    home();
</script>
```

**other_page.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/build/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/build/js/other_page.js"></script>
```

**The gulp file**

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var factor = require('factor-bundle');

gulp.task('build:scripts', function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: "static/src/js/",
        entries: [
            './common.js',
            './home.js',
            './other_page.js'
        ],
        debug: true
    })
    .plugin(factor, {
        outputs: [
            'static/build/js/home.js',
            'static/build/js/other_page.js'
        ]
    })
    .bundle()
    //Pass desired output filename to vinyl-source-stream
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('static/build/js/'));
});
```

**And a extract of package.son concerning Browserify**

```
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "foundation": "./bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js",
  "foundation-dropdown": "./bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jQuery": "$",
  "foundation": {
    "depends": [
      "jquery:$"
    ]
  },
  "foundation-dropdown": {
    "depends": [
      "foundation"
    ]
  }
},
```

The build is ok. But error happen when I load the home page : "Module not found 'home'"

What I am doing wrong ? 
Is it the good way to use browserify on multipage website ?

I made a repo for the complete project : https://github.com/JiDai/browserify-multipage